# How to use DateTime for time interval?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making a Flutter app chatbot.

If a visitor asks a question about outside shop opening hours, I want the bot to respond. If it's about inside shop opening hours I want a human to respond. What `DateTime` conditional can I use for this?
So far I have:

```
var dateUtc = DateTime.now().toUtc();
var now = DateTime.now();

var startHour =
    DateTime.utc(dateUtc.year, dateUtc.month, dateUtc.day, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0);
var endHour =
    DateTime.utc(dateUtc.year, dateUtc.month, dateUtc.day, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0);

if (now.toUtc().isAfter(startHour.toUtc()) &&
    now.toUtc().isBefore(endHour.toUtc())) {

  //Inside hour. Use human.

} else {

  //Outside hour. Use bot

}
```

But this does not work. Also if a user is in other time zone (before 00:00) sometimes it will always show outside hours. How to fix?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Can you come with some examples where you have hardcoded the time and can reproduce the problem? Is this Flutter on mobile or web? And just a tip, you don't need to call `toUtc()` when making comparisons with DateTime. The DateTime object itself know if the time is localtime or UTC and will convert automatically when needed.

Comment: On mobile. It always show inside hour

Comment: Well, it works fine here if I manually modifies `now` to be set at a localtime which is outside the range of opening hour. Therefore I ask for more detailed example which can be used to reproduce the problem and which is not depended on the value of `DateTime.now()` since we don't all live where you are. :)

Comment: For example try set local time `now` to one day before UTC time. Then it is always outside opening time. But this is wrong because it is still inside time. That make sense?

Comment: As mentioned, provide sample code that can reproduce the problem and that is not dependent on `DateTime.now()` and whatever your local time zone is.  The first step is to print out the current UTC time where the code does not behave as you expect.